# Is it possible to change an attribute value from another html file?

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a website right now and I want to change the aria-expanded value of an exapandable paragraph in another page when I press an anchor element in the main page. What will I need to change in my main.html so i can somehow change the aria-expanded value on the help.html file?

**main.html**

```html
<a href="help">
   <h2>Returns Policy</h2>
</a>
```

*help.html*

```html
<div class="accordion-item">
       <button id="accordion-button-3" aria-expanded="false"><span
        class="accordion-title">Returns Policy</span><span
        class="icon" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
        <div class="accordion-content">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod 
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Elementum sagittis vitae et 
            leo duis ut. Ut tortor pretium viverra suspendisse potenti.
            </p>
        </div>
</div>
```

//and this is the script used to expand the paragraph

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion button");

    function toggleAccordion() {
        const itemToggle = this.getAttribute('aria-expanded');

        for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            items[i].setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'false');
        }

        if (itemToggle == 'false') {
            this.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'true');
        }
    }

    items.forEach(item => item.addEventListener('click', toggleAccordion));
```

Comment: Is this anchor tag also directing the user to that "other page"?  It's not really clear to me what you're trying to do, or how you expect to make style changes on a page that isn't loaded in the browser...

Comment: If you are using iframe (or frames for that matter...please don't) and both pages opened at the same time than you'll need send messages from page to another via [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage). Otherwise store value in `localStorage` or cookies

Comment: Your `<a>` tag looks like a plain link. When it's clicked, given what you've posted, a new page will be loaded. Thus your question really doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: the `<a>` tag is just a place holder for now but that is what i want to do, I want to click that _clickable_ Returns Policy so when it redirects it to the **help.html** page it will automatically expands the Returns Policy Paragraph, what changes should I do with the `<a>` tag to make that happen?

Answer (score 0):

your button id is "accordion-button-3" so in querySeletorAll you need "#accordion-button-3"

`const items = document.querySelectorAll("#accordion-button-3");`

Comment: there's actually more buttons over there but only put one for example